# Cannot Add Answers on Career Profile

Tags: support, status-norepro, answers, jobs

My careers.stackoverflow.com profile is not finding any answers associated to my account (using the same openid login on careers, stack exchange, and stack overflow) and manually pasting in a link to one of my answers does not appear to do anything either.

Links:

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/kevinthompson
- [How can I have a template "view" in CodeIgniter 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247775/how-can-i-have-a-template-view-in-codeigniter-2-0/5249355#5249355)

Comment: How long have you been trying this? Your profile says that your account associations are currently changing, so perhaps it just takes a bit of time for that to complete?

Comment: Sorry about that Kevin.  I'm having some trouble reproing, though.  You don't see any answers to select when you click the "add an answer" link on the edit view of your profile?  Are you having some kind of javascript error?  What OS/browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Marking this as no-repro since I think it was a temporary thing.  If anyone else sees this problem we can revisit it.